# Multi-legged sign-out from Office 365 / Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, thinktecture-ident-server

I have scenario where we use Thinktecture Identity Server (IdSrv) as both an R-STS and a IP-STS, as well as a O365 / WAAD tentant as an additional IP-STS. The user choose which Identity Provider to use via the Home Realm Discovery functionality in IdSrv.

Now, implementing a unified WS-Federation wsignout from the RP, is difficult, since I can't get the signout process to work properly against WAAD (Against the Thinktecture IP-STS it works fine);

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you out.
>   We received a bad sign-out request.
>   If you wish to sign-out, please click the following link.

**ACS20028: The requested redirection URL is invalid.**

Well, the wreply URL parameter points to the RP, which the WAAD instance has no knowledge of.

> If I try to follow the Sign-Out link, I get
>   Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you out.
>   We received a bad request.

**ACS20026: The wtrealm parameter is missing or incorrect.**

I've tried to modify the URL directly so that its wreply points to the IdSrv (which really is an RP of the WAAD), but I can't get it to work.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Can you post your RP signout code?

Comment: WAAD sign-out does not work with multi-domain scenario for me as well. It looks like WAAD checks that `wreply` is one of the configured reply URLs. Obviously the check does not work correctly for sign-out, allowing only the first (or last) Reply URL, disallowing the rest with ASC20028 error.